# Values of $m$ such that $|x^2-2x+m| + 2x + 1$ has $3$ extrema

Tags: calculus, derivatives, quadratics, absolute-value

I was given the following question:

Find the values of $m$ for which the curve $y=|x^2-2x+m| + 2x + 1$ has $3$ extrema.

My teacher suggested that we should use the quadratic formula $(b^2-4ac)$ and check every case of it.

I am sure that there are three main cases of the inside of absolute value being $<0 ; =0 ; >0$.

The solution is $m<0$ but I do not know how to dig down into each case.

Comment: Simply using the determinant of the quadratic is not sufficient because of the extra $2x+1$ term. You should also use the fact that the derivative of $|u|$ is $sign(u)$ (do you see why?).

Comment: It sure be insufficient but by the fact that we cant draw the graph nor using sgn (because it is not taught), it is surely a pain.

Comment: Out of curiosity which grade level (or which course) is this question for? I will post a solution in a bit but it's quite subtle.

Comment: I am currently in 12th grade and this question is for city competition

Answer (score 1):

Note that your absolute value can be written as a piecewise function:

$$y = \begin{cases} x^2 - 2x + m + 2x + 1 = x^2 + m + 1 
\\ -(x^2 - 2x + m) + 2x + 1 = 4x - x^2 -m + 1 
\end{cases}$$

The domain of the piecewise function is determined by the value of $m$. I hope you understand why the piecewise function exists like such. If not, see the [Absolute Value Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value).

Consider, $x^2 - 2x + m > 0 \implies x^2 - 2x + m + 2x + 1 > 2x + 1, \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \iff m > 1$. Then, the absolute value would be redundant, and your function would be an ordinary +parabola; $x^2 + m + 1 \ge x^2 + 2$. Hence, there would not be $3$ extrema.

Therefore, our first condition for $3$ extrema must be that there are $2$ **real** solutions to the function, $-(x^2 - 2x + m) + 2x + 1$, since the $2$ of the extrema are these $2$ solutions.

Let these solutions be $x_1, x_2, x_1 \le x_2$.

$$x_1,x_2 = \dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}
\\x_1 = \dfrac{-4 - \sqrt{4^2 - 4(-1)(1 - m)}}{2(-1)} = 2 - \sqrt{5 - m}
\\x_2 = \dfrac{-4 + \sqrt{4^2 - 4(-1)(1 - m)}}{2(-1)} = 2 + \sqrt{5 - m}$$

We can then refine the domain to,

$$y = \begin{cases} x^2 - 2x + m + 2x + 1 = x^2 + m + 1 &x < x_1 \text{ or } x > x_2
\\ -(x^2 - 2x + m) + 2x + 1 = 4x - x^2 -m + 1 &x_1 < x < x_2
\end{cases}$$

The  $3$rd extrema occurs when there exists a maxima between $x_1, x_2$. This is a  maxima because the line $2x + 1$ is strictly increasing; $2x_1 + 1 < 2x_2 + 1 \text{ or } y(x_1) < y(x_2)$. Additionally, observe from above that $|x^2 - 2x + m| + 2x + 1 \ge 2x + 1$. The maxima can be calculated through the derivative:

$\big(-(x^2 - 2x + m) + 2x + 1\big)' = 0 
\\4 - 2x = 0 \implies x = 2
\\\therefore 2x_2 + 1 = 2(2) + 1 = 5$

We must have $x_2 > 2, y(x_2) > 5$ (observing $2x + 1$ strictly increasing),

$$
\\\therefore 4x_2 + 1 - x_2^2 - m = 4(2) + 1 - 2^2 - m > 5 
\\5 - m > 5
\\m < 0$$

Comment: can i may ask why the piecewise function having 2 cases where y>0 or y<0 rather than x^2 - 2x + m being <0 or >0

Comment: @Khanh Indeed you are correct. I will remove the incorrect range. Ideally, it would be best defined using the domain (roots) $x_1, x_2$, as done later on.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to tackle this problem if we understand how the function behaves on the graph.

The curve is the sum of an absolute quadratic function and a linear function.
[image: Absolute of a quadratic]
*Absolute of a quadratic*
[image: Linear]
*Linear*
[image: Sum of the two functions]
*Sum of the two functions*

**It is apparent that when there are three extrema, they occur at the following points:**

(1) The two points where the quadratic function hits the $x$-axis.

(2) The vertex of the quadratic function.

**There are two conditions to fulfil.**

(1) The quadratic function intersects the $x$-axis at two points. Otherwise, the absolute function cannot create the two kinks.

(2) The curve goes to opposite direction on the two sides of each kink. A counter-example is:
[image]

The slopes on both sides of the kink are upward so it is not considered an extrema.

$$\\$$
**Solution:**

To fulfil condition (1), we may use the discriminant.
$$b^2 - 4ac > 0$$
$$(-2)^2 - 4m > 0$$
$$m < 1$$

To fulfil condition (2), we may check the derivatives on the two sides of each kink. The kinks occur at
$$x^2 - 2x + m = 0$$
$$x = 1 \pm \sqrt{1-m}$$

**Case I: $x < 1-\sqrt{1-m}$**

$x^2-2x+m>0$

Hence, the curve can be simplified as $y = (x^2-2x+m)+(2x+1) = x^2+(m+1)$.

**Case II: $1-\sqrt{1-m}<x<1+\sqrt{1-m}$**

$x^2-2x+m<0$

Hence, the curve can be simplified as $y = -(x^2-2x+m)+(2x+1) = -x^2+4x+(1-m)$.

**Case III: $x > 1+\sqrt{1-m}$**

$x^2-2x+m>0$

Hence, the curve can be simplified as $y = x^2+(m+1)$.
$$\\$$
The derivative of $y = x^2+(m+1)$ is given by $y' = 2x$.

The derivative of $y = -x^2+4x+(1-m)$ is given by $y' = -2x+4$.
$$\\$$
That means, we want $2x$ and $(-2x+4)$ to have opposite signs at $x = 1 \pm \sqrt{1-m}$.

It requires that
$$\begin{cases}2(1-\sqrt{1-m})<0 \\
-2(1-\sqrt{1-m})>0 \\
-2(1+\sqrt{1-m})<0 \\
2(1+\sqrt{1-m})>0\end{cases}$$

The set of inequalities boil down to
$$\begin{cases}\sqrt{1-m}>-1\\
\sqrt{1-m}>1\end{cases}\Rightarrow\sqrt{1-m}>1\Rightarrow m<0$$

As we need both conditions (1) & (2) to satisfy, i.e. $m < 1$ and $m < 0$, the answer to your question is $m<0$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution which only ever considers two cases.

We will use the fact that the derivative of $g(u)=|u|$ is
$$
\frac{d}{du} g(u) = 
\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
1 & \text{for } u>0\\
-1 & \text{for } u<0\\
\end{array}
\right\} 
=: \text{sgn}(u)
$$

Let $h(x) = x^2-2x+m$, and differentiate

$$
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(g(h(x))+2x+1\right) \\
&= h'(x)g'(h(x)) + 2\\
&= (2x-2)\text{sgn}(x^2-2x+m)+2 \\
&= 
\left\{
\begin{array}{lr}
2x & \text{for } x^2-2x+m>0 \cdots \text{(case I)}\\
4-2x & \text{for } x^2-2x+m<0 \cdots \text{(case II)}\\
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align}
$$

To get extrema, we want $f'(x)$ to change sign. Let's look at each case: Case I changes sign at $0$ and case II changes sign at $2$, so we make a table of the signs:
$$
\begin{array}{lc|c|c}
x^2-2x+m \in
&  \text{A}=(-\infty, 0) 
& \text{B}=(0,2) 
& \text{C}=(2,\infty) \\
f'(x) \text{ case I} & - & + & + \\
f'(x) \text{ case II} & + & + & - \\
\end{array}
$$
Notice that if we only stay in case I, we will only get $1$ extremum. So we want to generate more extrema by choosing $m$ that allows $f'(x)$ to go between cases like I $\downarrow$ II $\uparrow$ I.

To do this, we try to solve $x^2-2x+m=0$. By the quadratic formula these are $1\pm \sqrt{1-m}$. So the roots (if any) are evenly spaced around $1$ by $\sqrt{1-m}$. Follow the table from left to right and label any extrema we find by E$1$ E$2,\ldots$, to see

$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{1-m} > 1 
&\iff m < 0 
\iff \text{ I} \downarrow \text{II in A (E1); } 
 \ + \to - \text{ around } 2 \text{ (E2); 
II} \uparrow \text{I in C (E3)}\\
\sqrt{1-m} \le 1 
&\iff m \ge 0 
\iff \ - \to + \text{ around } 0 \text{ (E1); (and that is all)}
\end{align}
$$

So $f(x)$ has three extrema if and only if $m<0$.